# #31 expression must have integral type

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some problems with my C code and get the error in the title. First off, Uint16 is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned int    Uint16;
```

I use two variables in the function where I get the error, they are defined as:

```
static Uint16 gCommandSent = 0;
Uint16 gnRF_TX;
```

I call the function like this:

```
Transmit_nRF24L01(gnRF_TX, &gCommandSent);
```

and the function definition is like this:

```
void Transmit_nRF24L01(Uint16 nRF_TX,Uint16 *CommandSent)
{
    switch(CommandSent)
    {
    case 0:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = W_REGISTER | nRF24L01_CONFIG;
        *CommandSent = 1;
    case 1:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = CONFIG_TX;
        *CommandSent = 2;
    case 2:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = W_TX_PAYLOAD;
        *CommandSent = 3;
    case 3:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = nRF_TX;
        *CommandSent = 4;
    case 4:
        disable_TX();
        GpioDataRegs.GPBSET.bit.GPIO59 = 1;
        *CommandSent = 0;
    }
}
```

and lastly, the declaration in the shared header file looks like this:

```
void Transmit_nRF24L01(Uint16 nRF_TX,Uint16 *CommandSent);
```

I get the error on the line "switch(CommandSent)". I need to be able to change the value of CommandSent so unfortunately I cannot remove the pointer... how do I get around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try changing the `switch` to `switch(*CommandSent)`

Comment: consider using `uint16_t` ; the way you have it now, it would be surprising for someone recompiling your code on a system with 32-bit ints to find that "Uint16" has 32 bits.

Comment: There is no reason to define your own fixed size type. `<inttypes.h>` contains fixed size types like `uint16_t`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just changed it and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: The switch misses a `default` branch.

Comment: It's not missing as much as me deciding not to include a default branch.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `break` statements, and you need to use dereferencing for the `switch`:

```
void Transmit_nRF24L01(Uint16 nRF_TX,Uint16 *CommandSent)
{
    switch(*CommandSent)
    {
    case 0:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = W_REGISTER | nRF24L01_CONFIG; break;
    case 1:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = CONFIG_TX; break;
    case 2:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = W_TX_PAYLOAD; break;
    case 3:
        SpiaRegs.SPITXBUF = nRF_TX; break;
    case 4:
        disable_TX();
        GpioDataRegs.GPBSET.bit.GPIO59 = 1; break;
    }
    *CommandSent = (*CommandSent + 1) % 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that I hadn't put a star there. I changed it and now it works just as it should.